# Node express always return index.html on debian

Tags: node.js, express

I have node express server, the server working correctly on windows system. But on debian always return index.html.

When I go to localhost:port/ its retrun index.html, index.html load some js files and images(fav ico) - content of this files is ALWAYS content of index.html... so.. where is a problem?

code:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const application = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 80

const PUBLIC_DIR = 'public'

application.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, PUBLIC_DIR)))
application.listen(port)

application.use(express.static('client/build'));  //use your build path my build path under the root folder is client/build
  const path = require('path');
  application.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client','build', 'index.html')); //use your build path my build path under the root folder is client/build
  });

//handle 404
application.use((req, res) => {
    res.send('404: Page not Found', 404)
});

//handle 500
application.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    res.send('500: Internal Server Error', 500)
});

console.log(['HTTP server running on ', process.env.HOST, ' / ', port].join(''))
```

Comment: Because the very first thing you defined is a wildcard `*`, which will **always** match anything. Think of it as a [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) and you haven't defined any routes either.

Comment: Why is this working on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change following line

```js
app.use(express.static('client/build'));  //use your build path my build path under the root folder is client/build
```

to

```js
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client','build')));
```

So app will get proper path of the build folder and will not fall in catch-all route for static resource requests.

Answer (score 1):

You declare your express instance as `const application = express()` but then you're using `app.use` on line 11. Maybe changing it to `application.use` will provide better results?